# protobuf c string decode

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

Experts, I need your help in decoding the string value in the protobuf-c message. Say the message

```
m { optional string id =0 }
```

the string is stored with a value "test", by using the C api `m.id = "test"` and pack it using `m__pack(&m,buf);` the message stream will look like `0a 04 74 65 73 74`, where my string value is `74 65 73 74` in ascii format. I try to get my string value back by using api `m__unpack(NULL,length,buf)` where `buf` contains the stream. Now when I try to print the string `printf("%s\n",msg->id)` I get seg fault. Shouldn't it print the ascii values(74 65 73 74)? Can you please help in getting the string value. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the `msg->id` string zero-terminated?

Answer (score 0):

solved..
its my mistake, i was printing the msg->id after the *free*_unpack api, hence the issue.
thanks for your time.